# Installing ruby with RVM cannot find <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

When typing

```
rvm install 2.6.0
```

I get this error:

```
file.c:23:10: fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CFString.h' file not found
#include <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am on OSX 10.14.4

I have the newest version of Xcode installed (10.2).

How can I fix my system?

Here is a link to my other posts on the ruby mailing list: https://rubytalk.org/t/installing-ruby-with-rvm-cannot-find-corefoundation-cfstring-h/74982

Comment: Older versions of Ruby, like 2.3.x, may not work on newer versions of macOS. Have you tried 2.5.x? 2.6 is current and the most likely to install without issues as that's where everyone's attention is focused at the moment.

Comment: I just updated the question to show 2.6.0, it still does not work

Comment: If `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` does not resolve your issue, and if completely removing brew and all installed brew packages followed by reinstalling brew (but NOT reinstalling your packages; allow the RVM installer to use brew to install anything it needs) does not resolve your issue then you should reinstall macOS from scratch and retry your operation.

Comment: Please post output of both `rvm config-get` and `gem env` ?

Comment: @anothermh The pkg installed and rvm installs now!

Comment: @lacostenycoder I want to make sure everything is correctly setup though between OSX ruby and the homebrew/rvm ruby. Here is the pastebin for the gem env: https://pastebin.com/raw/VXEPXgKq

Here is the one for the rvm config-get: https://pastebin.com/raw/vSXRSEdp

It is complaining about the PATH directory still. So I am afraid my path is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and type:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: @anothermh seriously thank you so much I have been searching all week. Where did you find that command? I haven't seen it anywhere hopefully someone else will see it here that needs header files.

Comment: [The last time you asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55525660/3784008) someone told you to read [this](https://rubytalk.org/t/installing-ruby-latest-on-mac-mojave-corefoundation-cfstring-h-not-found/74830/2) which links to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52509602/3784008); you said "_I came across that post and it pretty much leads to a dead end_" which is odd because the top voted comment on that post (with 22 upvotes) and the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/3784008) on that post (with 144 upvotes) say to do exactly this.

Comment: Wow I totally missed that command. I tried everything else that posts says. Either way the answer has around 5 possible solutions, and lots of text makes it very unclear which one reinstalls the header files. I went to apple’s website and downloaded a command line tools pkg and installed it and it did nothing. Same with reinstalling Xcode.